# Identify all strings in SQL Server code (red color - like in SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, string, search

I was not able to solve this by myself so I hope I didn't miss any similar post here and I'm not wasting your time.

What I want is to identify (get a list) of all strings used in SQL Server code.

Example:

```
select 'WordToCatch1' as 'Column1' 
from Table1 
where Column2 = 'WordToCatch2'
```

If you put above code to SSMS all three words in apostrophes will be red but only words 'WordToCatch1' and 'WordToCatch2' are "real" strings used in code.

My goal is to find all those "real" strings in any code.

For example if I will have stored procedure 10k rows long it would be impossible to search them manually so I want something what will find all those "real" strings for me and return a list of them or something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Double quotes for identifiers, e.g "Column1".

Comment: "For example if I will have stored procedure 10k rows long" - then you might be solving the wrong problem!

Comment: All three are really strings, to skip 'Column1' you would have to parse the SQL itself.

Comment: @MitchWheat You are right, it was just an example... in reality I have 100 procedures 100-300 rows long:)

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is, Column1 is nothing particular different compared to WordToCatch1 and WordToCatch2 - not unless you parse the SQL yourself. You could modify your query to take the quotes away from Column1 and it will show up coloured black.

I guess a simple regex will show up all identifiers after an AS keyword, which would be easier than fully parsing SQL, if all the unwanted strings are like that, and its not just an example.

Comment: Thanks for good idea, this can be one solution but I would still prefer tool able to parse the SQL and return what I want. I will probably need this to use repetitively in the future... Btw. if there is a case someone forgot to insert "as" word in front of columnName your method will not work:(

Comment: if someone forgot to insert an 'as' in front, you have a lot of manual work to do :-) OK, you want a SQL parser, [Microsoft has one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.aspx) for you though I know little of it.

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed MS got own parser lib!:)